# Dart - force a class to have a factory

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following models:

- Author
- Post

```
class Author implements Model {
  String name;
  String email;

  User({this.name, this.email});

  factory User.fromMap(Map data) {
    return User(
      name: data['name'] ?? 'Jon Doe'
      email: data['email'] ?? 'jon@doe.com';
    )
  }
}

class Post implements Model {
  User author;
  String content;

  User({this.name, this.email});

  factory Post.fromMap(Map data) {
    return Post(
      author: Author.fromMap(data['author']);
      content: data['content'];
    )
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I tell dart to "force" all of the models to have a `factory Model.fromMap(Map data)`?

The reason I want to do so is that I want to fetch these models from an API (JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make any requirements around the *static* shape of a class, because there is nothing you'd be able to accomplish with that information. In order to *call* `Post.fromMap` you need to specifically refer to `Post.fromMap`, you can't call `someVariable.fromMap()`. There has been some discussion around being able to add requirements to static interfaces, but nothing planned. https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/356